# How to plot a weighted graph of k-Neighbors in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have created a weighted graph of k-Neighbors using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph.html), I'm wondering if there is any way to plot it as a graph.

Here is the result of computation in form of array which I want to plot:

```
array([[0.        , 2.08243189, 0.        , 3.42661108],
       [2.08243189, 0.        , 3.27141008, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 3.27141008, 0.        , 1.57294787],
       [0.        , 3.29779083, 1.57294787, 0.        ]])
```

I just need to get some visualization of data, that's all I need.

---

**More details about the array:**

Each row represents a node and each column represents the weight of connectivity of that node with the other nodes.

For example: second column of first row (2.08243189) is the weight of connectivity from first node to second node.
Another example: second row, second column (0): the weight of connectivity from node 2 to itself.

The numbers represents euclidean distance.

Comment: Add more details about this array. What does the rows and columns represent?

Comment: Each row represents a node, each column represent the weight of connectivity with the other nodes. For example: second column of first row is the weight of connectivity of first node to second node. another example: second row, second column: the weight of connectivity from node 2 to itself.

Comment: In this case, what does the numbers (weights) mean? Does they represent the distances, or similarity, or closeness between the nodes. For example, why the weight is `2.08` for node 1 and 2, and `3.42` for 1 and 4?

Comment: Easiest way to plot similarity/distance matrices is usually to use a PCA to push it into 2D and then plot that.

Comment: @VivekKumar it's euclidean distance ...

Comment: Why is the distance between 0 and 3 not equal to distance from 3 to 0?

Comment: @VivekKumar The matrix only exists of the two closest neighbors for each node.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something simple like this where the size of the point gives a visual indication of the relative weight compared to the other values? Assume the array is named ar:

```
for i in range(len(ar)):
    for j in range(len(ar)):
        v = ar[i,j]        
        plt.scatter(i+1,j+1,lw=0,s=10**v)
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.xlabel('Row')
        plt.ylabel('Column')
        ticks = list(range(1,1+len(ar)))
        plt.xticks(ticks)
        plt.yticks(ticks)
```

[image]